# Proving that $R_2$ with the standard topology is normal?

Tags: general-topology

I'm having a hard time proving that $R_2$ with the standard topology is normal. I started off by trying to show that for any two disjoint closed sets, A and B, we could find balls (so since we're in $R_2$ open sets) around them, U and V, but I don't know how to guarantee that these two balls are disjoint from each other. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Not only the open disks (balls) are open, but also any union of those.

Comment: Do you mean the Euclidean plane $\Bbb R^2$?